# Avoid circular reference in domain model

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

this must be such a common scenario that there's been a lot written about it already, hopefully even a really good pattern.  I have a domain model in which a custom container contains entities.  For example (properties and interfaces excluded for brevity):

```
class Entity
{
    public int Id;
    public EntityContainer ParentContainer;
}


class EntityContainer
{
    public int Id;
    public IList<Entity> Entities = new List<Entity>();

    public void AddEntity(Entity entity)
    {
        entity.ParentContainer = this;
        Entities.Add(entity);
    }
}


class Main
{
    public Main()
    {
        Entity entity1 = new Entity();
        Entity entity2 = new Entity();
        EntityContainer entityContainer = new EntityContainer();
        entityContainer.AddEntity(entity1);
        entityContainer.AddEntity(entity2);

        // Can now traverse graph easily, e.g.
        Console.WriteLine("entity1's parent container ID = " + entity1.ParentContainer.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("Container contains at least this entity ID: " + entityContainer.Entities[0].Id);

    }
}
```

I can now easily traverse my object graph both ways, but have created a circular reference.  Would you create a third type to divorce the dependencies?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The model you have there doesn't allow an inverse relationship for more than one parent container, so most likely won't work the same way if you have an entity in multiple containers.

Comment: can you clarify how that is circular? you're creating a tree structure as far as I understand so I don't see where the circularity comes from

Comment: Entity has a reference to EntityContainer and EntityContainer has a reference to Entity.

Comment: Good point on the inverse relationship.  I need to update, but the example is probably ok for the purpose of the question.

Comment: Regarding the inverse relationship, if I were to add it to the above then I might just replace the parent container field in the 'Entity' class with a list of "EntityContainer".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with circular references, per se, and they are used extensively in the .NET Framework, e.g. XmlNode.OwnerDocument, Control.Parent.

If you need to traverse up the tree, then a back reference is fine to use.

In COM, circular references are tricky because if you were the set the container and all its children to nothing, then objects will not be cleaned up properly as the children still hold references to the parent.  However the .NET garbage collection has no problem with this the way it is implemented.

Comment: One problem I encounter with circular references is with serialization. Generally, if object A has B and object B has A, it won't serialize. This is particularly problematic when putting these objects in out-of-proc session state.

Answer (score 2):

Does the container need to know about the *type* of the contents? If not, generics can avoid this - i.e. `Container<T>`, where you *happen* to use `Container<Entity>`. Other than that; pushing the necessary details into an interface (or base-class) in an assembly that both can reference is a common approach.

Personally, I'd try to simply avoid the need for the child to know about the parent.

Also; note that if you *do* go down the abstraction (interface etc) route; this can have a big implication if you are using (for example) xml serialization.

---

(edit re comments)
OK; first: what problem is the circular reference (within an assembly) causing; if none, leave it alone. If there is a problem, then you'll need an extra type; presumably some interfaces to represent the concrete types - i.e. where `Entity : IEntity`, and `EntityContainer` only knows about `IEntity` (or vv with `IEntityContainer`, or both),

Comment: The child needs to know about its parent for performance reasons.

Comment: Generica wouldn't be suitable for the actual problem domain I'm modelling.  These are specific types and relationships.

Comment: Thanks for the update - I will be adding interfaces.  I think the general consensus of there's actually nothing wrong with circular references is the main take-away from this question.

Answer (score 1):

As so I don't see a problem with your class model but you could easily make a clean cut. Make Entity implement an interface IEntity and make EntityContainer hold a IList and unless you have a very specific reason for using IList you should considere IEnumerable, It would make it easy for the consumer of the EntityClass you use. Since passing any array of IEntity, or linq expression selecting IEntities would be possible

Comment: Calling Enumerable.ToList() on a List is most definitely not free, as it always produces a new list - so it'll have to make a copy, which is O(N).

Comment: @Pavel nope It's optimized to simply return the list object if it's called on a list

Comment: You're plain wrong. Crack open System.Core.dll with ILSpy and look at the implementation of `Enumerable.ToList`. It is literally as simple as `return new List()` plus an argument null check. This is quite intentional - the designers of LINQ did not want library clients to be able to downcast objects to something the library author didn't expect them to, and potentially mutate internal data. So all `To...()` methods will create a copy even if the original is already of that type. In contrast, the `As...()` return the original object.

Comment: @Pavel you're right I misremembered the optimization it does indeed always return a new list.

Answer (score 1):

Using circular referenced objects is ok in my book providing you are using some kind of lazy-loading pattern when designing those objects.

e.g.

You want to access: ***Company.Employee*** 
And in another scenario: ***Employee.Company***

Which makes a circular reference i.e. ***Company.Employee.Company.Employee*** etc.

If these properties are not lazy-loaded e.g. A Company object always loads its Employee property and the Employee object always loads its Company property then it aint gonna work too well when you introduce a data source.